# Транслятор из brainfuck в ассемблер

Tags: ассемблер, brainfuck, c++, linux

Хочу написать транслятор из bf в ассемблер. Но у меня проблема: как мне представить массив из 30000 символов?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

char array[30000];

Comment: это не ассемблер

Comment: В самом деле - это C (C++). 

А разве автор вопроса собирается писать транслятор на ассемблере ? 

Я, увидев метку c++ решил, что именно программа на нем будет читать исходники BF и создавать код на ассемблере (правда автор не сказал на каком).

Ассемблерный код, который генерит gcc -S для локальных статических массивов использует дерективу:

    .lcomm _имя,размер-в-байтах

а для глобальных:

    .comm _имя,размер-в-байтах

Локальные массивы (в стеке) естественно не именуются, используется известное компилятору смещение от начала текущего фрейма (адресуется регистром).

Comment: Скажите, а транслятор в ассемблер чем-то отличается от компилятора?

Answer (score -1):

В `FASM` можно так:`db 30000 dup(0)`